# Can can't get my first or logical pass to ignore a blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to ignore a logical argument in an `IF(OR())` if a blank exists.

```
=IF(OR(AND(C4>0,TODAY()-F4>250),AND(C4=0,TODAY()-D4>60)),"Sell Now", "Check back in 30")
```

At `TODAY()-F4>250` I get a Value error if there is no data in Cell F4. I have tried variants of modifying with ISNUMBER or ISBLANK but it throws off my Logical condition and gives me false negatives when it should return TRUE.

Can I modify it somehow where if a blank exists, to proceed to the second condition in the OR argument at `AND(C4=0,TODAY()-D4>60))` ? Thank you

I'm really just trying to say if this condition is true or this condition is true  - sell now, otherwise check back. If I have a blank on that first argument it throws it off.

Comment: A `#VALUE!` error suggests that you may have a blank string in `F4`, which is not actually a blank cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFERROR`:

If you still want the `C4>0` check to happen:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C4>0,IFERROR(TODAY()-F4>250,TRUE)),AND(C4=0,TODAY()-D4>60)),"Sell Now", "Check back in 30")
```

If you want to skip the `C4>0` check as well:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(AND(C4>0,TODAY()-F4>250),FALSE),AND(C4=0,TODAY()-D4>60)),"Sell Now", "Check back in 30")
```

It's not exactly apparent whether you want the second argument of `IFERROR` to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`; adjust according to whether you want the first condition to pass or not.